# Cassandra querying for latest data on multiple rows

Tags: python, cassandra, time-series, cql

I am cassandra newbie. I am collecting system status every 5 mins so I created this table,

```
create table sysportal (hostname text, logged_date text, logged_time timestamp, service text,  plugin_output text, status text, PRIMARY KEY((hostname, logged_date), logged_time, service, plugin_output, status));
```

Sample table is,

```
 hostname  | logged_date | logged_time          | service | plugin_output | status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 host1 |  2014-02-21 | 2014-02-21 07:25:30+0000 |    disk | DISK OK |     ok
 host2 |  2014-02-21 | 2014-02-21 07:25:31+0000 |    disk | DISK Warning |     ok
 host1 |  2014-02-22 | 2014-02-22 15:23:50+0000 |    disk | DISK OK |     ok
 host2 |  2014-02-22 | 2014-02-22 15:23:50+0000 |    disk | DISK Warning |     ok
 host1 |  2014-02-23 | 2014-02-23 15:23:50+0000 |    load | LOAD OK |     ok
 host2 |  2014-02-23 | 2014-02-23 15:23:50+0000 |    ping | PING OK |     ok
```

How do I get all host's latest data in single query ?

Using python currently I am doing this,

```
select logged_date, logged_time from sysportal limit 1; => In python save in variables
select hostname from sysportal;  => In python get distinct hosts
```

and then,

```
for i in hosts:
    select service from sysportal where hostname=i and logged_date=va1  and logged_time=var2
```

Can somebody advice if I can do this with single query in cassandra ?
Should I create other tables/column_families ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, since your hostname is part of your partition key, you can't.  Depending on your data size/load you can possibly create a new table that has "logged date" or some other column, as the partition key and has hostname as part of the clustering columns.

So your table could look something like this:

```
create table sysportal_by_date (
  hostname text,
  logged_date text,
  logged_time timestamp,
  service text,
  plugin_output text,
  status text,
  PRIMARY KEY(
    logged_date,
    logged_time,
    hostname,
    service,
    plugin_output,
    status
  )
) with clustering order by (logged_time DESC);
```

This would allow you to run a query that is:

```
select * sysportal_by_date where logged_date = <today> order by logged_time desc;
```

Comment: I'm not sure i fully understood it. Can you please explain on creating new table with logged_date(PK) | hostname  help ? So the tables would be existing sysportal host1|logged_date1|logged_time1|....   and another table logged_date1|host1  ? How can I map them ?

Comment: okay so ""select * sysportal_by_date where logged_date = <today> order by logged_time desc;""   <today> I have every 5 mins data for say 200 hosts ..  say 1 hour of data will have 2400 rows .. So when you say  "logged_date = <today>"  it will take all 2400 rows, and then order by logged time,  will  host1: 00, host2:00, host3:00 .... host1:05, host2:05, host3:05...  host1:10, host2:10, host3:10 .. and so on. Can you advice how do I can get latest data of each host ?

Comment: well that will give you the latest data for each host in that given hour, you could set the hour to the current hour.

Comment: Ok I got the results  host1: t1, host2, t1, host3:t1 .... host1:t2, host2:t2,host3:t3. 
I am just trying to understand when should I go with new table. Say i f I get request "Get mem,cpu of hostname=abc.* from time1 to time2"  then I should create a new table sysportal_by_host. Am I right (considerting I have 15k machines) ?